# Generalization of Fourier transform in higher dimension or other methods to find a "basis" for vector field function space?

Tags: functional-analysis, machine-learning, vector-fields

Some background: A [multilayer perceptron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilayer_perceptron) is the godfather of today's "AI". It roughly has the following structure as chained functions between vector space:
$$N(x)=f_n(...f_3(f_2(f_1(x))))=\hat{y}$$
where $x$ is typically a dataset and $\hat{y}$ a approximation to an relevant output. [For example](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-021-26434-1), data from a physics experiment $x$ mapped to a set of equations $\hat{y}$ that explains such data. This is done typically usually an algorithm called "back-propagation" which uses an "loss" function of $\hat{y}$ and some additional data $y$, these functions are usually distance functions in $\mathbb{R^m}$ which are differentiable and can be used with the chain rule to compute the derivative for the preceding $f_i$s. So here's my question:
Given a chain of functions $$f_i:\mathbb{R^u_i} \to \mathbb{R}^m_i$$
with composability: $$\mathbb{R}^u_{i+1}=\mathbb{R}^m_i$$ there should be a "space of differentiable functions" on $\mathbb{R}^u_1\to \mathbb{R}^m_{n}$. ***Is it possible to find a "basis" in the sense that their composition in this way "span" the entirety of this space?***

Here's my thinking so far:
A derivative of a function $$f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$$ is a linear map $$d:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^m$$ s.t. $$\lim_{h\in \mathbb{R}^n \to 0}\frac{|f(a)-f(a+h)-d(h)|}{|h|}=0$$ So $d$ and $f$ have basically the same "basis", so if you can find such a "basis" for $f$ you may be able to find it for $d$. My use of the word "basis" is based on my basic understanding of the Fourier transform is like giving a basis to the function space $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Are there analogous constructions of the Fourier in higher dimensions?

Comment: This is probably what you want: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem

Comment: This result is too "loose" to tell me anything about how to find ${f_i}$s, I'm more looking for a constructive proof one categorical level higher on finding a "compositional basis" for functional spaces that makes neural networks unique rather than an existence proof about approximation of functions. Anything can be approximated by anything "in the limit" or with "axiom of choice" lol

Comment: Well, no, that’s entirely false, which is why the universality theorems have conditions. None of this has anything to do with the axiom of choice, either. Anyway, if there’s any sense to your question at all, it’s pretty clearly the case that the uniqueness result you want is not achievable.